# Issue with preventDefault. Submitting form

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, forms

I have created this jQuery AJAX script for submitting a form:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    // process the form
    $('#reviewForm').submit(function(e) {

        $("#reviewError").hide();
        $("#reviewSuccess").hide();

        var formData = {
            'name'              : $('input[name=name]').val(),
            'email'             : $('input[name=email]').val(),
            'description'   : $('input[name=description]').val(),
            'one'           : $('input[name=price]').val(),
            'two'           : $('input[name=location]').val(),
            'three'             : $('input[name=staff]').val(),
            'four'          : $('input[name=service]').val(),
            'five'          : $('input[name=products]').val(),
            'shopID'            : $('input[name=shopID]').val()
        };

        // process the form
        $.ajax({
            type        : 'POST', // define the type of HTTP verb we want to use (POST for our form)
            url         : 'post/review.php', // the url where we want to POST
            data        : formData, // our data object
            dataType    : 'json', // what type of data do we expect back from the server
            encode      : true
        })
            // using the done promise callback
            .done(function(data) {

                if ( ! data.success) {

                    $("#reviewError").show();

                } else {

                    // ALL GOOD! just show the success message!
                    $("#reviewSuccess").show();

                }
            })

        // stop the form from submitting the normal way and refreshing the page
        e.preventDefault();
    });

});
```

Sadly the form submits though the normal way and not though the AJAX. Im at a loss to what the issue can be. I have tried the return false and such but that didn't work at all.

Comment: any error in your browser console

Comment: What about e.StopPropagation()?

Comment: Can you post your html as well?

Comment: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property '_renderItem' of null scripts-2.js:36(anonymous function)

Thats the only thing that I get back.

I would post the HTML but is rather large! Its got 5 rating sections and such!

Comment: Did you connect any other js file to this html file I mean scripts-2.js

Comment: Your code is working for me and no page refresh happen. So fault should be somewhere else.

Comment: Yes I too think the same and as per your error @Jiggles I think its error in  scripts-2.js file

Comment: My Aplogies I copied the wrong error. Uncaught ReferenceError: $ is not defined ?page=shop:459(anonymous function) which is the line: $(document).ready(function() {

Comment: `$ is not defined`?? I'm pretty sure that you forgot to add jQuery to your scripts, or that you are declaring jQuery after you declared that code.

Comment: Its the last bit of script on the page with other items on the page that use jQuery and they work fine!

Comment: You have forgotten to and jquery or it is invalid...

Comment: jQuery is included on the page.

Comment: Can you please post your completed code? because of some other reason your Jquery may fail to download to your page.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are missing **e.preventDefault();** at the begining of the submit(); and to use e.

```
$(document).ready(function(e) {

    // process the form
    $('#reviewForm').submit(function(e) {
         e.preventDefault();
        $("#reviewError").hide();
        $("#reviewSuccess").hide();

        var formData = {
            'name'              : $('input[name=name]').val(),
            'email'             : $('input[name=email]').val(),
            'description'   : $('input[name=description]').val(),
            'one'           : $('input[name=price]').val(),
            'two'           : $('input[name=location]').val(),
            'three'             : $('input[name=staff]').val(),
            'four'          : $('input[name=service]').val(),
            'five'          : $('input[name=products]').val(),
            'shopID'            : $('input[name=shopID]').val()
        };

        // process the form
        $.ajax({
            type        : 'POST', // define the type of HTTP verb we want to use (POST for our form)
            url         : 'post/review.php', // the url where we want to POST
            data        : formData, // our data object
            dataType    : 'json', // what type of data do we expect back from the server
            encode      : true
        })
            // using the done promise callback
            .done(function(data) {

                if ( ! data.success) {

                    $("#reviewError").show();

                } else {

                    // ALL GOOD! just show the success message!
                    $("#reviewSuccess").show();

                }
            })

    });

});
```

Hope this Helps.

Answer (score 0):

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    // process the form
    $('#reviewForm').click(function(e) {

        $("#reviewError").hide();
        $("#reviewSuccess").hide();

        var formData = {
            'name'              : $('input[name=name]').val(),
            'email'             : $('input[name=email]').val(),
            'description'   : $('input[name=description]').val(),
            'one'           : $('input[name=price]').val(),
            'two'           : $('input[name=location]').val(),
            'three'             : $('input[name=staff]').val(),
            'four'          : $('input[name=service]').val(),
            'five'          : $('input[name=products]').val(),
            'shopID'            : $('input[name=shopID]').val()
        };

        // process the form
        $.ajax({
            type        : 'POST', // define the type of HTTP verb we want to use (POST for our form)
            url         : 'post/review.php', // the url where we want to POST
            data        : formData, // our data object
            dataType    : 'json', // what type of data do we expect back from the server
            encode      : true
        })
            // using the done promise callback
            .done(function(data) {

                if ( ! data.success) {

                    $("#reviewError").show();

                } else {

                    // ALL GOOD! just show the success message!
                    $("#reviewSuccess").show();

                }
            })

        // stop the form from submitting the normal way and refreshing the page
        e.preventDefault();
    });

});
```

Use 'Click' event instead of 'Submit' will work definatly

Comment: one more thing attach click event on submit button not form